# How to disable has_many_association for rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I commented out the has_many , yet the same export page with has many after restart the rails server

```
 config.model 'User' do

  #   # You can copy this to a 'rails_admin do ... end' block inside your user.rb model definition

  #   # Found associations:

      # configure :canvases, :has_many_association 
      # configure :level, :has_many_association 
      # configure :tags, :has_many_association 

  #   # Found columns:

      configure :id, :integer 
      configure :name, :string 
      configure :email, :string 
      configure :raw_info, :serialized 
      configure :created_at, :datetime 
      configure :updated_at, :datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should remove the comments to enforce a specific configuration.

try this:

```
configure :canvases, :has_many_association do hide end  
configure :level, :has_many_association do hide end  
configure :tags, :has_many_association do hide end
```